# Mac-like terminal prompt?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I just saw in a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XD2O9EF58kI) a Mac terminal app with a feature I would really like to have in elementary OS default Terminal app.

Capture:

[image]

The prompt (little left arrow) is located *below* the line that displays the info (user and location). This is particularly useful when the folder one is located into, has a rather long name.

Can this be achieved at all with elementary's Terminal app?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it looks like "zsh". Have a look here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these instructions and will have a very similar result (take a look at the [screenshot](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-zsh-theme)):

```
$ sudo apt-get install zsh
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
$ curl -o - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-zsh-theme/master/install.sh | zsh
```

Open your ~/.zshrc file in an editor.
Change theme (probably line 8) to "spaceship":  `"ZSH_THEME="spaceship"`

Reload your terminal:

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

More info for zsh here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

More themes and their installation can be found here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/External-themes

There are many of them. Maybe you find a better one.

**After doing this your default shell ist 'zsh'. Follow [uninstall instructions](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#uninstalling-oh-my-zsh) if you want to go back to bash!**

Comment: Thank you mazienho. I believe you are right, and although the theme does not look *exactly* like the screen-capture, it look very similar. Cheers.